# No se como controlar la presentacion de graficos de excel desde pycharm, para luego poner esa grafica en un fichero HTML

Tags: pycharm, openpyxl

la intencion es hacer una grafica de lineas con los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aunque si me es posible hacer la grafica desde pycharm sin problema, la presentacion que obtengo no es la deseada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los puntos por los que viajan las líneas deberían de ser solo 4, por los 4 puntajes y las líneas deberían de ser 8, una por cada usuario además de que el nombre de las líneas no es el de los usuarios y no se como cambiar eso, a continuación les muestro el código usado en pycharm:

```
    ws = wb.active
    c1 = LineChart()
    c1.title = "Line Chart"
    c1.style = 13
    c1.y_axis.title = 'Puntuacion'
    c1.x_axis.title = 'Fase'

    data = Reference(hoja, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=9)
    c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data = True)
    rango = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=5)
    c1.set_categories(rango)

    hoja.add_chart(c1, "A12")
    wb.save("torne.xlsx")
```

Después de esto mi intención es añadir esa grafica a un fichero HTML pero he investigado y no se como hacerlo